# How to override an internal function

Tags: c#, sharepoint

How can i override a virtual internal function using reflection?

I have an abstract class in a sharepoint assembly (SPIisWebServiceApplication) that i want to implement.

In my logic i'm obligated to override the **IisApplicationName** property that i can see it using reflector it is writen like below:

> internal virtual string
>   IisApplicationName {
>       get
>       {
>           return base.Id.ToString("N");
>       } }

it is only internal it is not protected...

I don't want the IisApplicationName to be an id because it appears in the IIS.
I want to override it as they have done in other internal implementers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reflection is about *accessing* the structure of existing types, not *changing* it. (You can change the data stored in *instances* of types, but you can't change the *structure* of the type itself.)

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but reflection is unlikely to help you if you're trying to override a member.

Comment: @Gaby: It's impossible to say as you haven't explained what you're trying to do in nearly enough detail.

Comment: I've edited my post to explain my prob. Please let me know if you want farther information

Comment: @Gaby: This isn't a property you're *meant* to override within your own code. You claim you're "obligated" to override it: you can't. You're not meant to. Change your approach so that you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive from the class normally and override the function, which is presumably `protected virtual internal` (`private` cannot be `virtual`, and it would not need to be `internal` if it were `public`). Such an access specification allows the access model of *both* `interal` *and* `protected` -- i.e., the method can be accessed from classes in the same assembly *and* from derived classes.

Is there something that prevents you from doing this?

Comment: The Property i want to overrride is virtual internal. I've edited my post please let me know if you want me to explain more.

Comment: Then that property is an implementation detail that is not visible to you on purpose -- I expect that there is a natural way to achieve what you need without messing with that. The devs at MS don't make such elementary mistakes.